# if condition is being executed even after inside condition function with parameter returns false

Tags: c++, if-statement, return-value

```
bool isCycle(vector <int> adj[],int v)
{
    vector <bool> visited(v, false);
    for (int u = 0;u < v;u++)
    {
        if (visited[u] == false)
        {
           if(bfs(u, adj, visited,v));
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

even after function inside if condition returned false. Why is it executing the if condition ???

```
if(bfs(u, adj, visited,v));
       return true;
```

Comment: Does your editor have a function for automatically indenting the code? If yes, use that and `return true;` would be placed at the same indentation level as the `if` above it - which should tell you that something is wrong like Shooter pointed out below.

Comment: Like `ggVG=` in Vim ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(bfs(u, adj, visited,v));
       return true;`

has an extra ';' after the 'if' statement, which makes it execute the empty statement (the semicolon) if bfs() returns true, or nothing (since there is no 'else') if bfs() returns false.

This followed by the 'return true' which gets executed unconditionally.

Probably this is intended:

```
if(bfs(u, adj, visited,v)) // No semicolon here
       return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is probably happening:

You are in your for loop, and you visited[u] is equal to false. But then 
bfs(u, adj, visited,v)
evaluates to false, so the inner if statement is not executed. That keeps happening until you are done with the loop, so your function returns false.